# Configuring Routing Rules for WordPress+Nginx and WP-SuperCache?

Tags: nginx

How do you **set up routing rules** correctly with [**Nginx**](http://nginx.org/) to support [**WP Super Cache**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) for a WordPress (3.x) site?

Comment: You can use easyengine (http://goo.gl/Wzidcu) to setup WordPress with WP super cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@jschoolcraft**:

Does this articles address your question?

- [WordPress, Nginx and WP Super Cache](http://ocaoimh.ie/wordpress-nginx-wp-super-cache/)

If not, maybe there would be something in these?

- [HOWTO: Install WordPress On Nginx](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/)
- WordPress + [nginx Compatibility](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-compatibility/) Plugin
- [Howto nginx + wordpress + ubuntu shortest setup](http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/howto-nginx-wordpress-ubuntu-shortest-setup/)
- [Nginx front-end proxy cache for WordPress](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/nginx-front-end-proxy-cache-for-wordpress/)
- [WordPress Pretty Permalinks with Nginx](http://josephscott.org/archives/2010/06/wordpress-pretty-permalinks-with-nginx/)

Comment: The first link in Mike's response, straight from the SuperCache author is what you're looking for. Under Step 6), starting with '# if the requested file exists, return it immediately' are the rewrite rules to access the cached files from disk directly if they exist. This even bypasses WordPress entirely for static, cached content.

Comment: *@Joost Schurr* - Nice follow up!

Comment: Yeah, this answers the question, or certainly addresses it.  It looks like there was a comment in the first post about not having a closing </html> tag, I get the same thing...

but my view source looks like:
</div> <!-- div ft --> 
 
</body> 
</html> 
 
<!-- Page not cached by WP Super Cache. No closing HTML tag. Check your theme. --> 

Looks like it's there to me.

Comment: @Jeff Schoolcraft: Good deal!

Comment: Except for the no closing HTML part.  looks like a bunch of plugins use ob_start() which might be causing my problems.

Comment: @JeffSchoolcraft you may also find the links in this answer interesting.

Answer (score 1):

[Dan Collis-Puro](http://www.linkedin.com/in/dancollispuro) has a great article on **how Harvard Law used Nginx as a front-end proxy for WordPress**, and has released a WordPress plugin which outputs some HTTP headers to interface with Nginx, also available in the article. The readme has information on how to get things set up.

Here's the article:

- [**Nginx as a front-end proxy cache for WordPress**](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/djcp/2010/01/nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-cache-for-wordpress/)

Note that at Harvard Law, they've completely abandoned all WP-side caching in favor of Nginx. The additional complexity in the WP side, they found, was completely unnecessary after getting nginx set up.

Comment: *@mitcho* - Very nice find!